# Use one column to create another ones

Tags: sql

I have this table :

```
PRODUCTNUMBER   AttributeTypeName               TextValue
1020M              Core Style                    Fashion
1020M               Length/Weight                 LONG
1020M              Quilted/NonQuilted             NonQuilted
```

I want to create a query to give me this table

```
 AttributeTypeName = Core Style --> TextValue  Stylecode
 AttributeTypeName =Quilted/NonQuilted  --> TextValue  FabricCategory
 AttributeTypeName =Length/Weight  --> TextValue  LableCode
```

I am using case but I am getting 3 rows for each item and i want to see just 1 row like this

```
PRODUCTNUMBER   Stylecode    FabricCategory      LableCode

1020M             Fashion       NonQuilted       LableCode
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? This operation is called "pivoting" and it's done differently depending on what you are using.

Answer (score 0):

just use uniona all

```
    select 'AttributeTypeName=',
    max(case when AttributeTypeName='Core Style'
    then  TextValue end) from table
   union all
    select 'AttributeTypeName=',
    max(case when AttributeTypeName='Quilted/NonQuilted'
    then  TextValue end) from table
     union all
    select 'AttributeTypeName=',
    max(case when AttributeTypeName='Length/Weight'
    then  TextValue end) from table
```

Comment: This will give you redundant records with a bunch of nulls

Answer (score 0):

You could try join on same table

```
select  a.PRODUCTNUMBER
 , a.TextValue StyleCode 
 , b.TetValue FabricCategory
 , c.TextValue  LabelCode 
from my_table a 
left join my_table b on a.productnumber  = b.productnumber 
    and b.AttributeTypeName ='Quilted/NonQuilted'
left join my_table c on a.productnumber  = c.productnumber 
    and c.AttributeTypeName ='Length/Weight'
where a.AttributeTypeName ='Core Style'
```

and if also the first attribute is missing

```
select  a.PRODUCTNUMBER, d.TextVale  StyleCode , b.TetValue FabricCategory, c.TextValue  LabelCode 
from (
    select  PRODUCTNUMBER, AttributeTypeName  
    from my_table 
)  a 
left join my_table b on a.productnumber  = b.productnumber 
    and b.AttributeTypeName ='Quilted/NonQuilted'
left join my_table c on a.productnumber  = c.productnumber 
    and c.AttributeTypeName ='Length/Weight'
left join my_table d on a.productnumber  = d.productnumber 
    and d.AttributeTypeName ='Core Style'
```

Comment: Ah... using `LEFT JOIN` in case the other attributes are missing. What if the first one is missing?

Answer (score 0):

This will work for most databases, if your list is going to just be these three columns

```
SELECT PRODUCT_NUMBER,
       MAX(CASE WHEN AttributeTypeName = 'Core Style' THEN TextValue ELSE NULL END) AS StyleCode,
       MAX(CASE WHEN AttributeTypeName = 'Length/Weight' THEN TextValue ELSE NULL END) AS FabricCategory,
       MAX(CASE WHEN AttributeTypeName = 'Quilted/NonQuilted' THEN TextValue ELSE NULL END) AS LableCode,      
  FROM TEST_DATA
 GROUP
    BY PRODUCT_NUMBER;
```